# Using SQL to categorize multiple columns in a row, each with their own categorization logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, accounting, categorization

Seeking suggestions for how to do the following in SQL (I have an approach but it seems very inefficient, described below). I have a ‘transactions’ table that has the following general structure – each row pertains to a particular ‘order ID’ and ‘transaction type’, with columns of information about the transaction:

| TYPE | ORDER_NO | revenue | shipping | rebates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SALE | 100001 | $55.22 | $7.00 | $(5.22) |
| REFUND | 100001 | $(55.22) | $0 | $5.22 |
| ADJUSTMENT | 100001 | $(8.00) | $(2.00) | $0 |
| SALE | 100005 | $40.00 | $4.00 | $0 |
| REFUND | 100005 | $(32.00) | $(4.00) | $0 |

I need to categorize the values in columns for accounting purposes, but each column has separate categorization logic depending on the value of TYPE for the row. In the extreme case where all values in 'order # 10001' above ended up in separate categories, the desired result would look like this:

| TYPE | ORDER_NO | revenue | shipping | rebates | accounting_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SALE | 100001 | $55.22 |  |  | 101 |
| SALE | 100001 |  | $7.00 |  | 102 |
| SALE | 100001 |  |  | $(5.22) | 103 |
| REFUND | 100001 | $(55.22) |  |  | 104 |
| REFUND | 100001 |  |  | $5.22 | 105 |
| ADJUSTMENT | 100001 |  | $(8.00) |  | 106 |
| ADJUSTMENT | 100001 |  |  | $(2.00) | 107 |

My approach has been to pull the transactions table as a temp table, and then have a series of sub-queries each pulling only one of the columns (and 0 for the others) and assigning the category based on TYPE and whichever column is being pulled in that sub query. I then union all the results back together (sample query below). But this seems cumbersome (as verified by performance). Thanks in advance for any thoughts on more efficient ways to approach this.

Current query (a concatenation of TYPE and the hard-coded column name stands in for accounting code here - e.g. 'SALES | revenue'):

```
with TT as
   (select * from transactions)
select 
   TYPE,
   ORDER_no,
   sum(revenue) as revenue,
   0 as shipping,
   0 as rebates,
   CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue') as acc_code

FROM TT

group by 
   TYPE,
   Order_no,
   CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue') 

UNION

…(repeat process for next column, setting others to 0)
```

Comment: I don't think your current logic (3 `union`s) is that bad. However, I'd recommend `union all` since you know they can't possibly be duplicates. I'm also not sure why you're using the CTE... is there a reason you don't just select from `transactions` directly (instead of `TT`)?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: What's the datatype for the revenue field?

Comment: Your expected result's acc_code values all are integers, but they are created as `CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue')`. Or is acc_code not the same as accounting_code?

Comment: @EdmCoff in the real data there are more like 12 columns and I noticed the performance really starting to tank as I added subsequent unions. My thought on the CTE would be that this would perform better than going out and hitting the original table fresh each time, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @jarlh My example is confusing but I am concatenating TYPE with a hard-coded value for the column in question, e.g. result for first row would be 'SALES | revenue'. This is a stand-in for the actual accounting code for now but you could envision a look-up table where each TYPE/column name combo relates to the correct accounting code.

Comment: I'm skeptical the CTE will improve performance as it's written, but presumably you could have the CTE do all the `group by`s  once and then `union all` it. Do you have an index on `(type, order_no)`?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, have a consistent example. A [mcve].

Comment: Are there multiple sales/refunds/adjustments per order_no? In your current sample data, those `group by`s seem unnecessary.

Comment: @EdmCoff usually only one sale, refund or adjustment event order, although I have seen a few with more. And as noted, there are multiple other columns I have not mentioned here. I've likely way oversimplified things in the attempt to make a clear/compact post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I recommend considering something like the following, at least as a starting point:

```
WITH TT AS (
 SELECT
  type,
  order_no,
  sum(revenue) as revenue,
  sum(shipping) as shipping,
  sum(rebates) as rebates
 FROM 
  transactions
 GROUP BY
  type, order_no
)
SELECT type, order_no, revenue, 0 shipping, 0 rebates, CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue') acc_code
FROM TT
UNION ALL
SELECT type, order_no, 0 revenue, shipping, 0 rebates, CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue') acc_code
FROM TT
UNION ALL
SELECT type, order_no, 0 revenue, 0 shipping, rebates, CONCAT (type,' | ', 'revenue') acc_code
FROM TT
```

The CTE `TT` will do the `group by` once, likely improving performance (I'm skeptical your current CTE is helping performance-wise). If performance is still a concern (as per your comments), an index on `(type, order_no)` might help optimize the `group by`. Besides performance, this version of the CTE reduces the complexity of each of the main queries that aren't `union`ed together (e.g. the `group by` isn't repeated) making it easier to read and maintain.

Note that this handles the `acc_code` like your sample query does (as opposed to your expected output). You could adjust it if necessary, but that seems tangential to your question.

It's a little unclear what data types the revenue/shipping/rebates are. I'm assuming it's safe to `sum` them as numerics, since your existing query `sum`s them and it's implied that your existing query works.

Comment: thanks indeed. I already started heading in this direction based on your earlier feedback and performance is definitely improved. Dropped all my GROUP BY statements and aggregation (sum) in the sub-queries for individual columns, and switched to UNION ALL (as suggested, duplicates are not going to occur unless there is a problem somewhere else in the query). All of the data types for these columns are numeric, by the way.